# Why would an instance method from a helper be available in one controller but not another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Inside `ApplicationController` I have:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include GeoHelper
```

Inside `GeoHelper` I have the following instance methods:

```
GeoHelper.instance_methods
=> [:get_ip, :maxmind_locate, :locate_ip, :relocate]
```

Inside `StylesController` I run `locate_ip` with no trouble in my `show` method, but when I try and run the same method from `HearingAidsController` I see:

```
undefined local variable or method `locate_ip' for HearingAidsController:Class
```

Both controllers inherit from `ApplicationController` so what gives?

I tried restarting my server, but still seeing the error.

**Update**

Something really weird is going on in this particular controller. I am getting similar errors even when just putting a test method RIGHT INSIDE in the controller and trying to call it.

```
def test_method
  binding.pry
end
```

Then running within the show method with `test_method`

```
undefined local variable or method `test_method' for HearingAidsController:Class
```

Comment: usually you do not need to `include <helper>`. Just use `helper(:all)` in your `ApplicationController`

Comment: Doesn't `helper(:all)` only add to the view context? I am calling `locate_ip` inside of the controller.

Comment: This might be out of the blue, but is this helper tied to some specific geolocation gem, or is it a part of your own custom code?

Comment: Interesting, the method _should_ be available. Would you care to create a [mcve] and post it to github or something?

Comment: It's a custom helper file in `app/helpers/geo_helper.rb`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev not sure how easy this would be for me, but I will if no one has any clues to solve this.

Comment: @Abram: it is very likely that you'll find the problem in the process. Happens very often to me :)

Comment: See update above.

Comment: You see, preparing an mcve did help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pulling my hair out over a mysterious issue (with a misleading and unhelpful error message), I finally worked it out.

Without posting all my code, the issue was that the `locate_ip` method was outside of the show method! I pasted a bit of code from an old controller and didn't realize I accidentally closed the show method with an `end` that was copied across. Going to leave this Q&A here for anyone else that runs into this. **Count those ends!!**

Comment: Ah yes, the clue was there all along, but I didn't notice it: `method 'locate_ip' for HearingAidsController:Class`